# How to Disable SSL verification while running groovy script URL?

Tags: java, security, ssl, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a local groovy scipt for testing which works fine on prod server but on local I am getting SSL error as :

```
Caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java_net_URLConnection$getOutputStream$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at url.processRequest(url.groovy:8)
    at url$processRequest.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at url.run(url.groovy:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    ... 7 more
```

What workaround can I do to remove SSL verification in local groovy script?The line whihc gives error:

```
def post = new URL("https://abc.deg.com").openConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the connection to a HttpsUrlConnection and inject an unsafe trustmanager which does not validate anything. In that way you will remove all SSL verifications. I do not recommend this as it is unsafe, but here is the snippet which you can use:

**UnsafeTrustManager**

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

class UnsafeTrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {

    @Override
    void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0]
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new UnsafeTrustManager()}, null)
def sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory()

def post = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://abc.deg.com").openConnection()
post.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
```